# Creating a Storybook instance including stories from multiple libraries in a Nrwl Nx workspace

Tags: storybook, angular-storybook, storybook-addon, nx-angular

I have a storybook instance for every NX libs (core,icons), and I would like to have only one storybook instance that collect all the stories present in different libs.

I am using
NX 13
Angular 13
@nrwl/storybook 13

Do you know if it is possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

Take a look at this talk: https://youtu.be/bvSN1nSKFPk

This blog is slightly outdated but it also talks about the same thing: https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/creating-a-storybook-instance-including-stories-from-multiple-libraries-in-a-nrwl-nx-workspace-89009a2bddf7